# IntelliJ IDEA: how to get notifications about changes in repository

Tags: intellij-idea, version-control, notifications

Is it possible to get notifications about changes in repository in Intellij Idea?
Well one can notice that changes were made under repository tab or when opens file which was edited by someone. In this case IDE shows "Outdated version. Updated by ..."

I would like to see something more noticeable than that.

Answer (score 4):

You can activate a check which runs in background and notifies you when files changed "on server".

You can do so in Settings -> Version Control -> Background: "Changed on server" conflicts: Check every [] minutes.

Comment: I have this setting enabled, but see no difference to what it was before